# Upload image error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am building an E-commerce website, and I want to upload images from my computer to change the products' image, I couldn't upload/update the product's image because I got an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post').
I will appreciate it if anyone can help me with this issue!

Here is the Error screenshot image:
[image: error image]

//uploadRouter.js:

```
import multer from "multer";
import express from "express";
import { isAuth } from "../util";

const uploadRouter = express.Router();
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination(req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, "uploads/");
     }, filename(req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, `${Date.now()}.jpg`);},
      });

 const upload = multer({ storage });

 uploadRouter.post("/", isAuth, upload.single("image"), (req, 
    res) => {res.send(`/${req.file.path}`);});

  export default uploadRouter;
```

// server.js:

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import path from "path";
import userRoute from "./routes/userRoute";
import productRoute from "./routes/productRoute";
import orderRouter from "./routes/orderRouter";
import uploadRouter from "./routes/uploadRouter";


dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 
   "mongodb://localhost/amason", {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
   useCreateIndex: true,
  });

app.use("/api/uploads", uploadRouter);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/products", productRoute);
app.use("/api/orders", orderRouter);


 const __dirname = path.resolve();
 app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 
   "/uploads")));

 app.get("/", (req, res) => {
   res.send("Server is ready");});

 app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });});

 const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
 app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`);});
```

// productEditPage.jsx:

```
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
  import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
  import { detailsProduct, updateProduct } from 
     "../actions/productActions";
  import LoadingBox from "../components/loadingBox";
  import MessageBox from "../components/messageBox";
  import { PRODUCT_UPDATE_RESET } from 
     "../reducers/actionTypes";
  import { axios } from "axios";
  import NavBar from "../components/navbar";
  import Footer from "../components/footer";


function ProductEditPage(props) {
  const productId = props.match.params.id;
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [brand, setBrand] = useState("");
  const [countInStock, setCountInStock] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => 
     state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

  const productUpdate = useSelector((state) => 
     state.productUpdate);
  const {
     loading: loadingUpdate,
     error: errorUpdate,
     success: successUpdate,
   } = productUpdate;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (successUpdate) {
      props.history.push("/productlist");
    }
    if (!product || product._id !== productId || successUpdate) {
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATE_RESET });
      dispatch(detailsProduct(productId));
    } else {
      setName(product.name);
      setPrice(product.price);
      setImage(product.image);
      setCategory(product.category);
      setCountInStock(product.countInStock);
      setBrand(product.brand);
      setDescription(product.description);
    }
   }, [product, dispatch, productId, successUpdate, 
    props.history]);

 const submitHandler = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   dispatch(
    updateProduct({
      _id: productId,
      name,
      price,
      image,
      brand,
      category,
      countInStock,
      description,
      })
    );
   };


  const [loadingUpload, setLoadingUpload] = useState(false);
  const [errorUpload, setErrorUpload] = useState("");

  const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;

  const uploadFileHandler = async (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];

  const bodyFormData = new FormData();

  bodyFormData.append("image", file);
  setLoadingUpload(true);
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post("/api/uploads", 
      bodyFormData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
     },});

     setImage(data);
     setLoadingUpload(false);
   } catch (error) {
     setErrorUpload(error.message);
     setLoadingUpload(false);
     console.log(error);
   }};


  return(
       <div className="container  ">
         <div className="row content ">
           <div className="row justify-content-between 
             content_header mt-4">
             <div className="col-4">
             <p>Edit Product {productId}</p>
         </div>
       </div>
       {loadingUpdate && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
       {errorUpdate && (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorUpdate}</MessageBox>
      )}
      {loading? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ): error? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className="row ">
            <form
              className=" edit mt-5 mb-5 col col-lg-8 "
              onSubmit={submitHandler}
            >
              <div className="row g-3">
                <div className="col mb-3">
                  <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
                    Name
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control "
                    id="name"
                    value={name}
                    placeholder="Enter name"
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="col mb-4">
                  <label htmlFor="price" className="form-label">
                    Price
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="price"
                    value={price}
                    placeholder="Enter price"
                    onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="row g-3">
                <div className="col mb-4">
                  <label htmlFor="brand" className="form-label">
                    Brand
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="brand"
                    value={brand}
                    placeholder="Enter brand"
                    onChange={(e) => setBrand(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="col mb-4">
                <label htmlFor="image" className="form-label">
                  Image
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="image"
                  value={image}
                  placeholder="Enter image"
                  onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="mb-4">
                <label htmlFor="imageFile" className="form- 
                label">
                  Image File
                </label>
                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="file"
                  id="imageFile"
                  label="Choose Image"
                  onChange={uploadFileHandler}
                  multiple
                />
                {loadingUpload && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                {errorUpload && (
                  <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorUpload} 
                  </MessageBox>
                )}
              </div>

              <div className="row g-3">
                <div className="col mb-4">
                  <label htmlFor="countInStock" className="form- 
                  label">
                    CountInStock
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="countInStock"
                    value={countInStock}
                    placeholder="Enter countInStock"
                    onChange={(e) => 
                    setCountInStock(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="col mb-4">
                  <label htmlFor="category" className="form- 
                  label">
                    Category
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="category"
                    value={category}
                    placeholder="Enter category"
                    onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="mb-4">
                <label htmlFor="description" className="form- 
                label">
                  Description
                </label>
                <textarea
                  className="form-control"
                  id="description"
                  value={description}
                  placeholder="Enter description"
                  onChange={(e) => 
                  setDescription(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="row g-3">
                <div className="col mb-4 ">
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn- 
                  secondary ">
                    Update
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>)}
```

Comment: It looks like somewhere on the frontend part you try to read property of an item that doesn't exists, or is not populated yet at the time of reading. Probably if you upload complete code from component `productEditPage.jsx` there will something.

Comment: Looks like a client-side error, so somewhere in your React code there's `xyz.post` and `xyz` is undefined

Comment: Sounds like `axios` is undefined

Comment: @BlackH3art Thanks for your response. I just uploaded the full code of the component 'productEditPage'.

Comment: @ChrisG It's either 'uploadRouter.post(..)' in the uploadRouter.js or 'axios.post("/api/uploads", bodyFormData,..' in the productEditPage.jsx? But the uploadRouter and axios are both defined...

Comment: @epascarello axios has been imported from 'axios', I just updated the complete code.

Comment: The problem is this: `import { axios } from "axios";` which is supposed to be `import axios from "axios";` (note that you don't need axios client-side, browsers have fetch() now) (also note that the error message is pointing you at the exact function and line)

Comment: @ChrisG, I deleted 'import { axios } from "axios"', and got another error as"src/screens/ProductEditPage.jsx Line 84:30:  'axios' is not defined"

Comment: You're not supposed to delete it, you're supposed to fix it. It's supposed to be `import axios from "axios";` (just remove the curly braces; they caused you to import `axios.axios` instead, which doesn't exist)

Comment: @ChrisG You are right! Just tried and it works perfectly, thanks pretty much for helping me to figure out this issue 